# OCaml - Access Derived Functions from Another Module

Tags: ocaml, ppx

If a record is defined in a module in lib and it contains a `deriving` annotation that generates functions, how can those functions be used in another module?

For example, the `yaml`/`ppx_deriving_yaml` opam module contains a `[@@deriving yaml]`. If `[@@deriving yaml]` is applied to a record, functions are generated, such as `{record_name}_to_yaml`, which converts a record to a Yaml data structure.

Example: When `[@@deriving yaml]` is added to the `book` record, when compiled, there will be several functions generated, one being `book_to_yaml`.

```ml
(* ./lib/books.ml *)
type book = { 
  title: string;
  authors: string list
} [@@deriving yaml]
```

But if you try and access `book_to_yaml` from outside the `Books` module, it is unavailable.

Why is that function unavailable? How is it accessed?

```ml
(* ./bin/main.ml *)
let () = 
  let (b: book) = { title = "Cryptonomicon"; authors = [ "Neal Stephenson" ] } in
  Yaml.pp Stdlib.Format.std_formatter (book_to_yaml b);
                                 Error ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My assumption is that this is something specific to how deriving and modules work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer why, but is one way I found around the issue.

Lets assume the library is named 'bookstore':

```
(* ./lib/dune *)
(library
  (name bookstore)
  (libraries yaml)
  (preprocess
    (pps ppx_deriving_yaml)))
```

A function can be defined in the module with the record, which directly exposes the generated function. In this case `book_to_yaml` will be exposed with a function called `convert_book_to_yaml`.

```
type book = { 
  title: string;
  authors: string list
} [@@deriving yaml]

let convert_book_to_yaml = book_to_yaml
```

Now you can access `convert_book_to_yaml` by either adding `open Bookstore.Books` or directly with the full namespace `Bookstore.Books.convert_book_to_yaml`.

```
(* ./bin/main.ml *)
let () = 
  let (b: Bookstore.Books.book) = { title = "Cryptonomicon"; authors = [ "Neal Stephenson" ] } in
  Yaml.pp Stdlib.Format.std_formatter (Bookstore.Books.convert_book_to_yaml b);
```